# how to retrive the username of the current user after login in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the user current name after a log in. I need to display the name in the page, like **welcome user** . Please help me, my current code is given below

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand("Select name,password From registration", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if (txt_name.Text == dr[0].ToString() && txt_pass.Text == dr[1].ToString())
            {
                Response.Redirect("logout.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                label4.Text ="Invalid Username/Password";
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can use a session var like `Session["name"] = dr[0].toString()` before redirecting.

Comment: This code appears to log people out if their username and password match a row in the database. Is this what you intend?

Comment: You know you can use parameters in the query to at least filter the resultset on username? That way you don't get all 1000's of users from the db.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [ASP.NET membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
string userName = Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

However, obviously you are not using it (i strongly recommend). Why do you redirect to `logout.aspx` when the user successfully provided his username and password?

Apart from that you're not using the provided informatiuons at all in your query.

```
SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand("Select name,password From registration", con);
```

So you should use parameters to filter for the correct record:

```
using(var cmdr = new SqlCommand("Select name,password From registration where name=@name and password=@password", con))
{
    cmdr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", userName);
    cmdr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
    if(cmdr.ExecuteReader().HasRows)
    {
        // user + password correct
    }
    else
    {
        // user or password incorrect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Membership.GetUser().UserName in a membership provider.  Under no circumstances should you run the code you have there.  It is asking for a hack.  You should not be loading the passwords into memory and you are going to have performance issues as you gain more users because of your loop through all users!

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand("Select name,password From registration", con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (txt_name.Text == dr[0].ToString() && txt_pass.Text == dr[1].ToString())
        {
            Session["UserName"]=dr[0].ToString(); // OR Session["UserName"]=txt_name.Text;
            Response.Redirect("logout.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            label4.Text ="Invalid Username/Password";
        }
    }
```

}

You can fetch the session values in HTML(if your using it in your application)

```
<div>
Welcome <%=HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the identity of the user from the `User` property in code-behind.

```
myLabel.Text = User.Identity.Name;
```

The full namespace etc. for this is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

Reference for `HttpContext.User` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

Answer (score 1):

put the username in a session

```
Session["username"] = dr[0].ToString();
```

then on the other page

```
if Session["username"] != null
{
  String username = Session["username"].ToString();
}
else
{
  Page.Redirect("login.aspx");
}
```

You can check each different page

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally use built-in ASP.NET Forms Authentication - see [this article](http://bradkingsley.com/securing-asp-net-pages-forms-authentication-c-and-net-4/) for quick start. Coming to your question, on successful login, you should use line such as

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txt_name.Text, true);
```

This would store the user name into authentication cookie and which can be subsequently retrieved using code such as `User.Identity.Name` that you can user anywhere in your pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the username in session object and get username anywhere in the application if session is present

But you have to update your query also, The way you are calling is not good approach

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con1"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand("Select name From registration where name = @username and password = @password", con);
        cmdr.Parameters.Add("@username", txt_name.Text.trim());
        cmdr.Parameters.Add("@password", txt_pass.Text.trim());

        SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader();

        if(cmdr.ExecuteReader().HasRows)
        {
             Response.Redirect("logout.aspx");
             Session["userName"] = txt_name.Text.trim();
        }
        else{
        //Error page path
        }               
        //DOn't forget to close the connection when you Open it
      con.Close();
    }
```

You should learn more from some tutorials:

1. http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson01
2. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

..and if you're just wanting to use the `User` object:

```
var username = User.Identity.Name;
```